# Angular 4: How to correctly pass data from component to html

Tags: angular, types

I have some trouble understanding a simple task, basically I have a controller like this:

**app.componet.ts**

```
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { FlexLayoutModule } from "@angular/flex-layout";
import * as io from "socket.io-client";
var b;
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})

export class AppComponent {
  freqValue = [2,3];
  myData: Array<any>;
  autoTicks = false;
  invert = false;
  max = 15;
  min = 0;
  showTicks = true;
  step = 1;
  thumbLabel = true;
  vertical = true;
  color = 'primary';
  mode = 'determinate';
  //value = 50;
  socket : any;
  prova : any;
  @Input() valueSlider: number;

  constructor(){
    this.socket = io('localhost:3000');
      this.socket.on('value', function(a){
      b = a;
      console.log(a);
      console.log(b);
      this.valueSlider = b;
    });
  }
}
```

and a page like this:
**app.component.html**

```
...
  <div fxLayout="row wrap" class="nopad">
    <md-slider class="example-margin" [disabled]="disabled" [invert]="invert" [max]="max" [min]="min" [step]="step" [thumb-label]="thumbLabel"
      [tick-interval]="tickInterval" [value]="valueSlider" [vertical]="false" fxFlex="100%">
    </md-slider>
  </div>
...
```

I'm triyng to pass valueSlider from my TS to the HTML as a property of `<md-slider>`but without success...does anyone can explain me?
Thanks

Comment: do you have a plunk of what you did ?

Comment: @Fawad nope..I'll try to make one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using Angular Material, your general logic should work. Two thoughts though, first of all your structuring of the HTML attribute is odd... `value={{valueSlider}}` ignoring the fact that the quotation marks should be there, it would likely be better to structure it as such `[value]="valueSlider"`.

Next, I'm wondering if the `[disabled]="disabled"` is causing you some issues. While a slider can be disabled, the documentation (and the source code) doesn't lead me to believe that it is a public attribute you can modify.

---

### **UPDATED**

I think you have a scoping issue.

```
 constructor(){
    this.socket = io('localhost:3000');
      this.socket.on('value', (a) => {
      b = a;
      console.log(a);
      console.log(b);
      this.valueSlider = b;
    });
  }
```

Change the constructor to that above. The use of the term `function` rather than a lambda may prevent you from editing the `valueSlider` which is outside of the functions scope.

Comment: you are right I'm using angularmaterial, I changed the code to what you wrote but with no good, I'm adding the whole TS code for a better understanding

Comment: Edited to include the whole TS file

Comment: Updating answer

Comment: Yes! That's worked as a charm! add it as an answer and I'll approve it as correct! Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**app.component.html**

```
<md-slider ... [value]="valueSlider"> ... </md-slider>
```

Comment: how abou the declaration of valueSlider?

Comment: md-slider.component.ts `@Input() valueSlider: number;`
app.component.html `<md-slider ... [valueSlider]="valueSlider"> ... </md-slider>`

Comment: In the html [valueSlider] is not a property.. I need to dinamically set [value] wich is the "position" of the slider something like [value]="sliderValue"

Comment: You are right. I made a mistake. `md-slider` is one component of Angular Material. I forgot.